# How to identify network bottleneck

Tags: networking

I have problem with communication with Azure server and I'm trying to identify the cause.

I have very slow download rate (around 200 kB/s). The weird thing is it is very specific for given network I communicate over - my assumption is there is something wrong with some provider in the middle.

So far I've been able to do these observations:

1. From Azure to our office, I have upload rate around 200 kB/s
2. Upload speed from Azure to different servers (for example Digital Ocean) is pretty good, around 5 MB/s
3. Home, I have 2 internet providers. From one, speed is the same as from office, 200kB/s and from other it is about 500 kB/s
4. BUT, here is the catch. If I use VPN either home or in the office,
   I'm able to get to very good speeds - around 5 MB/s.

So both ends - Azure and office/home ISP are OK, problem must be somewhere on the route.

How to identify which provider is the bottleneck? And how to solve this kind of problems?
Ideally, I'd need something like `traceroute` just not for latency but for download/upload speeds.

Comment: traceroute **is** the tool for this. Compare traceroute results between the 200KiB/s cases and the 5MiB/s cases and see if all the slow cases traverse the same backbone provider, or especially the same peering connection between two providers, that none of the fast cases use. You'll probably discover the two providers are having a spat over their peering arrangement and one of them is retaliating by refusing to provision enough bandwidth for that peering connection. If that's the case, you don't solve it, you work around it, perhaps with VPN.

Comment: Forgot to mention: Use `whois` to find who owns any IP addresses in the traceroute results that don't have inverse-DNS records (that is, hops that only show up as IP addresses, not hostname).

Comment: I do have traceroute reports from office, both home ISPs and various VPNs and there are some nodes which are suspicious, but I don't know which node exactly is the real cause of the problem. VPN might be good as workaround, but I'd need to solve it anyway because it is also causing poor website performance for our customers. Ideally I'd like to identify the exact node causing the problems and then probably contact that provider and try to figure it out with them.